# Storage issue in web Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables, symlink

I have the issue with storage/uploads/my-folder-name

Everything works perfect in local, but I get broken image icon on the web

I save my links to each image in DB as 'storage/uploads/my-folder-name/file.jpg'

But if I change this path to 'storage/app/public/uploads/my-folder-name/file.jpg' the image is shown correctly

I try to show the image in yajra datatable

I have deleted the storage folder from my public folder and created symbolic link again

So everything should be working but it is not

The filesystem:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', 
        false),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

Comment: This sounds like a configuration issue either in your web server or in your Laravel filesystem. Consider sharing more on the changes you've made to `config/filesystems.php` or the config of your webserver. For more info see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem for filesystem config and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment for deployments.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks for the advise. I will read deployment paragraph more closely. Edited the first post, added filesystem